# LateInitializationError: Field 'XXXX' has not been initialized

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

so I am trying to run my application after fight with many errors. after gradle, I receive an error "LateInitializationError: Field 'myAppTheme' has not been initialized."

The following LateError was thrown building SignInScreen(): LateInitializationError: Field 'item' has not been initialized.

The relevant error-causing widget was: SignInScreen.dart:70:40
The signin page has animations that are late but nothing after that.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP0CG.png)

Below is my main.dart.

```
import 'package: flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screens/account/signin.dart';
import 'screens/homeScreen.dart';
import 'services/auth.dart';
import 'themes/maintheme.dart';

//==================This file is the Splash Screen for the app==================

late BuildContext _context;
late AuthService authService;
late ThemeData myAppTheme;

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: SplashScreen()));
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  void initState() {
    //Call the Class so that the constructor is called
    authService = AuthService();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _context = context;
    //Initialize the theme
    myAppTheme = getMainThemeWithBrightness(context, Brightness.dark);

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: myAppTheme,
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                    "assets/images/icon.png",
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Mera Store\nVisit, Scan, and Go",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "Poppins",
                          fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
                          color: Colors.grey),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}

Future<void> mainNavigationPage() async {
  if (blIsSignedIn || kIsWeb) {
    if (userProfile.containsKey("Theme")) {
      myAppTheme = userProfile[heme"] == "Light Theme"
          ? getMainThemeWithBrightness(_context, Brightness.light)
          : getMainThemeWithBrightness(_context, Brightness.dark);
    }

    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      _context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()),
    );
  } else {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      _context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SignInScreen()),
    );
  }
}
```

signin.dart page, this is where the application is meant to go to after gradle is completed.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:spar_store/screens/homeScreen.dart';
import 'package:spar_store/widgets/buttons.dart';
import 'package:spar_store/widgets/dialogboxes.dart';
import '../../main.dart';

//==================This is the Login Screen for the app==================
class SignInScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignInScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _SignInScreenState createState() => _SignInScreenState();
}

class _SignInScreenState extends State<SignInScreen>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  //Animation
  late AnimationController _animController;
  late Animation<Offset> _animOffset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    //For animation
    _animController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 3000));
    final curve =
        CurvedAnimation(curve: Curves.decelerate, parent: _animController);
    _animOffset =
        Tween<Offset>(begin: const Offset(0.0, 0.35), end: Offset.zero)
            .animate(curve);

    Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      _animController.forward();
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    //Animation
    _animController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double size =
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
            ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
            : (!kIsWeb)
                ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
                : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2;

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Container(
            child: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomStart,
          children: <Widget>[
            Opacity(
              opacity: 0.15,
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/animations/amazon-go.gif",
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                fit: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
                    ? BoxFit.fitHeight
                    : BoxFit.fitWidth,
              ),
            ),

            //Body
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    //Title
                    Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(35, 50, 5, 20),
                        child: FadeTransition(
                          opacity: _animController,
                          child: SlideTransition(
                            position: _animOffset,
                            child: Text("Hello there!",
                                style: myAppTheme.textTheme.bodyText1,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                          ),
                        )),

                    //Description
                    Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(35),
                        child: FadeTransition(
                          opacity: _animController,
                          child: SlideTransition(
                            position: _animOffset,
                            child: Text(
                                "Let us get started by signing into Mera Store with Google.\n\nOnce you are logged in, your prefrences will get saved, and you will be able to start shopping right away!",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: size * 0.04,
                                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                    color: Colors.white),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                          ),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),

                //Get the login Button
                Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40), child: getLogInButton())
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }

  //Get the login button
  getLogInButton() {
    return primaryRaisedButton(
      context: context,
      text: "Log In using Google",
      textColor: myAppTheme.backgroundColor == Colors.white
          ? Colors.white
          : Colors.black,
      onPressed: () {
        //LOGIN USING GOOGLE HERE
        showLoading(context);

        authService.googleSignIn().then((user) {
          if (user == null) {
            //Login failed
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                // return object of type Dialog
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: const Text("Failed to log in!"),
                  content: const Text(
                      "Please make sure your Google Account is usable. Also make sure that you have a active internet connection, and try again."),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
                    TextButton(
                      child: const Text("Close"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            //Navigate to the HomeScreen
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
            );
          }
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

any help will be welcomed

Comment: did you tried to change it from `late ThemeData myAppTheme;` to `ThemeData? myAppTheme` ?

Comment: Yes... errors all document